# jQuery hiding bootstrap table in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC driven site which displays records in a table. The table is a bootstrap 3 table. If there are no records I have a div which is shown. On the advice of another user I modified the view so that the table is rendered alongside my "there are no records" div.

Things I have in my application:

1. In my CSS I have set the table display: none
2. At the top of my JS file I do this...

   ```
   var absenceRows = $("#absencesTable tbody").find("tr").length;

   var $absTable = $("#absencesTable");

   var emptyAbsenceDiv = $("#no-absences");

   console.log(absenceRows);

   if (absenceRows === 0)
   {
      emptyAbsenceDiv.show("fast");
      $absTable.hide("fast");
   }
   else
   {
      emptyAbsenceDiv.hide("fast");
      $absTable.show("fast");
   }
   ```
3. I then have an AJAX call where I get data back:

   ```
    $("#chosenDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {

       var formattedDate = moment(e.date._d).format('DD/MM/YYYY');                    

       $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
           $("#absencesTable, #no-absences").fadeOut('0');
           $("#loading").show();
       });
       $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
           $("#loading").hide();
           $("#absencesTable").fadeIn('200');
       });

       var ajaxOptions = {
           url: absenceDateUrl,
           type: 'post',
           contentType: 'application/json',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: '{selectedDate:' + JSON.stringify(formattedDate) + '}'
       };    

       $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(function (data) {

           console.log(data);
           if (data !== null && data.length !== 0) {
               renderData(data);
           }
           else
           {
               console.log("No data! " + $("#absencesTable").is(":visible"));
               hideAbsences();

           }
       });
   });
   ```
4. In renderData I construct my data then show the table and hide my no-absences div

   ```
   $("#no-absences").hide("fast", function () {
       $("#absencesTable").show("fast");
   });
   ```

   This works fine BTW.
5. If no data is returned hideAbsences() gets called

   ```
   if ($("#absencesTable").is(":visible")) {
       $("#absencesTable").hide("fast");
       $("#no-absences").show("fast");
   }
   ```

I know I didn't need to check if the table is visible but I'm at the point where I'm trying out everything.

When there is no data my table isn't being hidden. I get both the div and table being shown.

Here is my View for reference.

```
    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
{
    <div class="well well-lg" id="no-absences"><h3>Everybody is in! There are no absences today :)</h3></div>
}

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="absencesTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Date Out
            </th>
            <th>
                Return Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Absence Type
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.FullName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.DateFrom.Value.ToLongDateString()
                    <span class="label label-default">@item.AbsencePeriodFrom.PeriodText</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.DateTo.Value.ToLongDateString()
                    <span class="label label-default">@item.AbsencePeriodTo.PeriodText</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.AbsenceType.AbsenceTypeText
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When data is returned the display property of the table is set to "display:table" but I don't think that's the reason my show/hide isn't working. I could be wrong. I just want to hide the div and show the table and vice versa not both.

FYI I did try to replicate this in jsFiddle but I couldn't replicate the error (http://jsfiddle.net/f2r9mdah/). I'm thinking something is funky with my jQuery or the View.

Comment: Have you turned on the console in your browser to check for errors?

Comment: There are no errors.

Comment: @ArminderDahul Is it hitting the console.log line?

Comment: @Josh Yes it is which is why this is soooo weird. If $("#absencesTable").is(":visible") is returning true/false why can't I hide the damn thing!?! Grrrrrr!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after a lot of headaches I found a solution. I don't understand why it worked but it does.

When the date in the calendar control is selected I have an ajax call. I wrapped my code in a try/catch block:

```
$("#chosenDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {

        try
        {
            console.log("$absTable = " + $absTable.is(":visible"));
            console.log("emptyAbsenceDiv = " + emptyAbsenceDiv.is(":visible"));

            var formattedDate = moment(e.date._d).format('DD/MM/YYYY');                    

            var ajaxOptions = {
                url: absenceDateUrl,
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{selectedDate:' + JSON.stringify(formattedDate) + '}'
            };    

            $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(function (data) {

                console.log("inside ajax done = " + data);
                if (data !== null && data.length !== 0) {
                    renderData(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    hideAbsences();
                }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            //throw Exception;
        }
    });
```

Also, just for good measure, I wrapped the table inside a div and used hide and show on the new div. Adding the div didn't make the code work, only the try/catch block did.

I'm not sure why this is working. Why isn't show/hide on a table element enough? Is this a Bootstrap 3 problem, or the [calendar control](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) I'm using...? If anyone else has any ideas please let me know.